# Can't mount DVD on lubuntu 20.04: no media is in the drive error

Tags: lubuntu, dvd, cd-drive

For command `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/mydvd` I get this error:

```
mount: /media/mydvd: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

eject is working properly
drive is working
disk is a new disk with audio data written on

Comment: Does not just putting the disk in the drive cause the system to see it? Is it a data disk or a commercial disk? I use home made data disk every day and never have to mount them. Put in the drive and it auto mounts.

Comment: Check if you can see damage on the surface of the disk; scratches and similar. If it is a self created disk (e.g. DVD-R...) then you may be able to recover the data by polishing it to a temporary working state with car paint "rubbing" compound (lay dvd flat on wet rug/towel or similar and use your power tools to polish it).

Comment: It's a fresh home made disk. But probably it was made on windows

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the problem was either with disk or with windows where it was recorded. The same disk written on Windows 10 was read without any trick.
Also unreadable disk was DVD RW, not R, may be it could be a problem.